# What's the difference between data section and aux region in perf_event_open()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64, perf, armv8

I'm studying the Statistical Profiling Extension(SPE) for Armv8 recently. During data sampling and reading there is little documentation and I have a question that I can hardly understand.

There is a ring buffer to record sampled data which is called a ring buffer. A ring buffer is treated as two kinds:data section and aux region. According to the [manual pages of linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html),  'The AUX region allows mmap-ing a separate sample buffer for high-bandwidth data streams (separate from the main perf sample buffer)'.

**Q1:** How to understand 'high-bandwidth data streams'? What data or events may the data streams include? Is it hardware specified that what data is streamed into AUX buffer ? Does the member `sample_type` of `perf_event_attr` just indicate what data to store in data section?

**Q2:**
If I sample with `arm_spe_0/store_filter=1/` at 1024 period, (`.type =65;.config = 1<<34;.sample_period =1<<10,.wakeup_events=1`), I can read and parse aux region at every interrupt. How could I read the corresponding sample in data section to the sample of aux region( both sample are collected at the same time exactly)